# Is there a way for a Django Project running on an Apache Server bilaterally communicate with a python script outside of the Django Project Scope?

Tags: python, django, apache, websocket, communication

I have a Django project running on an Apache2 server for a web application that shows the status of certain external drives. I used to have some linux commands called in a python script that dealt with mounting/unmounting hard drives inside the project. However I had to move the commands to a new python script outside the Django Project in the home directory because the computer didn't recognize the changes of mount/unmount of the drives since it was hidden inside the virtual environment inside the Django project beforehand. I now need this outside python script to communicate to the Django project's python script to tell if a drive was mounted along with the Django project to tell the python script to unmount a certain drive.

I tried creating a WebSocket to provide bidirectional communication as pipes are only a single direction. But I can't get the WebSocket to connect/run when it's called in the Django app.

```
def Tcp_connect( HostIp, Port):
    global s
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HostIp, Port))
    return

def Tcp_Write(D):
    s.send(D + '\r')
    return 

def Tcp_Read( ):
    a = ' '
    b = ''
    a = s.recv(1)
    while a != '\r':
        b = b + a
        a = s.recv(1)
    return b

def Tcp_Close( ):
    s.close()
    return


def start(self,request):
    Tcp_connect( '127.0.0.1', 17098)
    Tcp_Write("checkBefore")
```

it doesn't connect when start method called.

Comment: What do you mean by "external python script"? Hosted on a different machine?

Comment: stored in the home directory of the same machine but not inside the Django Project

Comment: Take a look at Django channels to handle WebSockets

Comment: @AlbinAntony so I would have to switch from WSGI to ASGI but would I also have to switch from using Apache2 to Daphne?